# How to parse <math> tag of wikitext to html using wiky.js?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, math

I need to parse `<math>` tag to `$` and `<math display ="block">` to `$$` using [wiky.js](https://github.com/Srijancse/OfflineExtension/blob/master/modules/wiky.js). This javascript is mainly using regex to do that.

For eg :

`<math> x^2 + 1 = 0 </math>` becomes: `$ x^2 + 1 = 0 $.`

And `<math display="block"> x^2 + 1 = 0 </math>`  becomes:  `$$ x^2 + 1 = 0 $$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ rex:/<math>(.*?)<\/math>/mgi, tmplt:"$$$1$$" }
{ rex:/<math *display *= *"?block"?>(.*?)<\/math>/mgi, tmplt:"$$$$$1$$$$" }
```

Comment: Where to add this exactly?

Comment: I suppose in the `wikiblocks` array.

Comment: It's not parsing correctly. If I write `<math> x^2 + 1 = 0 </math>` or `<math display="block"> x^2 + 1 = 0 </math> ` , it shows the result this : `<p>$1$</p>`

Comment: @SrijanAgarwal Sorry, I've updated the code: try now. And, if you want to remove the paragraph tag, try to inser the parsing rules in the `wikiinlines` array.

Comment: So, the code is coming now properly for `<math></math>` tag but not for `<math display="block"></math>`. It is displaying with `$` not with `$$`

Comment: It does not seem possible. In JS regex `$` is escaped with `$$` and `$$` with `$$$$`. Look at [here](https://regex101.com/r/wO0jT7/1) for a running example.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457976/how-to-parse-ordered-list-of-wikitext-to-html-using-wiky-js