# How to parse ordered list of wikitext to HTML using wiky.js?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, wikitext

I need to parse ordered list of wikitext to html using [wiky.js](https://github.com/Srijancse/OfflineExtension/blob/master/modules/wiky.js). This javascript is mainly using regex to do that.

E.g.

```
# Item1
# Item2
# Item3
# Item4
## Sub-item 1
### Sub-sub-item
```

is displayed as

```
1.Item1
2.Item2
3.Item3
4.Item4
    1.Sub-item 1
       1. Sub-sub-item
```

I need to get the HTML version of the code. Currently wiky.js uses the old version of parsing ordered list which is not supported by Wiki Editor now.

Comment: You may consider to flag and/or upvote my answer, it took me at least one hour to reach a working solution.

Comment: Hey @horcrux I did accept it. Since my reputation is not 15 yet, I couldnt do the up button. I'm really thankful for the answer. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I'm glad if it could have helped, I took it as a challenge :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped. :) @horcrux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following:

```
{
    rex: /^((#*)[^#].*(\n))(?=#\2)/gm,
    tmplt: "$1<ol>$3"
},
{
    rex: /^((#+).*(\n))(?!\2|<ol)/gm,
    tmplt: "$1</ol>$2.$2$3"
},
{
    rex: /#(?=(#+)\.#+\n(?!\1))/gm,
    tmplt: "</ol>"
},
{
    rex: /(<\/ol>)[#.]+/gm,
    tmplt: "$1"
},
{
    rex: /^((#+).*(\n))(?=\2[^#]|<\/ol)/gm,
    tmplt: "$1</li>$3"
},
{
    rex: /^(<\/ol>(\n)*)#+/gm,
    tmplt: "$1</li>$2<li>"
},
{
    rex: /^#+/gm,
    tmplt: "<li>"
}
```

Hoping they are executed in this order. This will cover a potentially infinite recursion level of `<ol><li></li></ol>` tags.

I don't explain you the code 'cause I've used some dirty expedients whose logic it's hard to unfold.

Comment: The code works fine if I don't add it to wiky.js. If I add it to wiky.js, it conflicts with the <p> tag. How can I remove the conflict, any help?

Comment: So this is what happening. 

`# First
# second
## Second-First

#### z
#### y
#### x
*** Third Point
## Second-Second [ftp://www.facebook.com FacebookFTP]
## Second-Third [http://www.google.com Google Here] 
# third`

If I'm using this to parse to html,


`<p># First
# secon
## Second-First</p>
?(p_uuu)
<li class="uuu">Third Point
## Second-Second <a href="ftp://www.facebook.com">FacebookFTP</a>
## Second-Third <a href="http://www.google.com">Google Here</a> 
# third
</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>`

This is what is getting displayed.

Comment: First, the code is not expected to be used togheter with pointed lists. Second, you have added the code in the inverse function part, that is the part where it's HTML to be parsed and converted to wiki (and with `<math>` you have done the contrary). Are you sure of what you are doing?

Comment: I did add this code to wikiinlines as well, the place where I added `<math>` tag. When I added there, this goes the result :
`<li> Item1
# Item2
# Item3
# Item4
## Sub-item 1
### Sub-sub-item`